# Ping Service to stop OpenShift Application from IDLE?

Tags: cloud, openshift, redhat

I am running a lightweight API in the OpenShift Cloud. I just realized that after 48h the application goes into IDLE mode. Is there kind of a ping service to avoid this issue?

best

M

Answer (score 22):

The OpenShift Online Bronze Plan is actually a free upgrade OpenShift offers in exchange for adding a credit card to your account. The Bronze Plan disables application idling and adds support for team management and custom SSL certificates. You don't have to pay anything and you still get three Small gears for free.

Just upgrade to Bronze - don't mess with all the Pingdom/Uptimerobot garbage. Check out the updated pricing page(s), I think they're making this pretty clear now:

- https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing
- https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing/plan-comparison

UPDATE: Small gears now idle after 7 days of inactivity on the Bronze (and Silver) Plan, versus 24 hours of inactivity on the Free Plan. Production gears (Small.highcpu, Medium, and Large) still never idle.

Comment: That's nice, if you live in US or Europe. For those of in the Rest of the World, the option to upgrade from a free plan is not available. I can't figure why OpenShift has this policy, it's not a usual thing for IaaS or PaaS providers.

Comment: I have upgraded to bronze plan but my application still idles, any suggestion please, because can't find support

Comment: Contact the OpenShift Online Team: https://developers.openshift.com/en/contact.html

Comment: How do we make sure that our gears don't go beyond the upper limit of the free tier?  I'm worried that I'll unknowingly use a great deal of disk or auto-magically start "scaling".

Answer (score 7):

You could also pay for a bronze account with a paid gear and it won't idle. It is because you are in the free tier that we idle if nobody is accessing your app. Just an explanation.

Comment: okay thx for the answer but I don't want to pay ;) At Heroku you can do this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480337/easy-way-to-prevent-heroku-idling) but I like the Dashboard of OpenShift.

Comment: Yeah and Heroku will idle you just like we do. I understand just trying to give another option ;)

Comment: Downvoted because this answer suggests the bronze tier always costs money... The answer from luciddreamz is clearer on this.